# Why is MySQL with FORMAT ignoring ORDER?

Tags: mysql

The first MySQL query works fine, however, it isn't formatted to look like money and with just dollars. The second one does the formatting correctly, but it is ignoring the ORDER and leaves average_sales not in ORDER. Could there be something with using CONCACT and FORMAT causing a problem? Thanks!

First one, the ORDER is correct:

```
select Region,AVG(sales) as 'Average_Sales_by_Region', count(*) as '# of Dist in state'
from dist, Regions_US
where dist.state=Regions_US.State
group by Region
ORDER BY Average_Sales_by_Region DESC;

+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Region             | Average_Sales_by_Region       | # of Dist in state      |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Mountain           |                    20216.2162 |                      74 |
| West North Central |                    18267.5000 |                      40 |
| South Atlantic     |                    16225.2809 |                     178 |
| East South Central |                    14966.6667 |                      30 |
| West South Central |                    13704.3840 |                     125 |
| East North Central |                    12668.3544 |                      79 |
| New England        |                    11915.6250 |                      32 |
| Pacific            |                    11552.8083 |                     120 |
| Middle Atlantic    |                    10291.6031 |                     131 |
| Alaska-Hawaii      |                     8150.0000 |                       4 |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

But I've been asked to change it so that Average_Sales_by_Region shows dollar amounts with no cents. So the top figure of 20216.2162 needs to be $20,216.

So my second one while it formats the money correctly, it ignores the ORDER:

```
select Region,CONCAT('$', FORMAT(AVG(sales), 0)) as 'Average_Sales_by_Region', count(*) as '# of Dist in state'
from dist, Regions_US
where dist.state=Regions_US.State
group by Region
ORDER BY Average_Sales_by_Region DESC;

+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Region             | Average_Sales_by_Region       | # of Dist in state      |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Alaska-Hawaii      | $8,150                        |                       4 |
| Mountain           | $20,216                       |                      74 |
| West North Central | $18,268                       |                      40 |
| South Atlantic     | $16,225                       |                     178 |
| East South Central | $14,967                       |                      30 |
| West South Central | $13,704                       |                     125 |
| East North Central | $12,668                       |                      79 |
| New England        | $11,916                       |                      32 |
| Pacific            | $11,553                       |                     120 |
| Middle Atlantic    | $10,292                       |                     131 |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I'm stuck here, I don't know why ORDER BY Average_Sales_by_Region DESC works in the first one, but it doesn't in the second one. The only difference is the use of  CONCAT('$', FORMAT(AVG(sales), 0)) in place of AVG(sales). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this query

```
select Region,CONCAT('$', FORMAT(AVG(sales), 0)) as 'Average_Sales_by_Region', count(*) as '# of Dist in state'
from dist, Regions_US
where dist.state=Regions_US.State
group by Region ORDER BY AVG(sales) DESC
```

This way you order like the first query but display result like second one

Answer (score 1):

You can still order by the unformatted average sales.

```
select Region,CONCAT('$', FORMAT(AVG(sales), 0)) as 'Average_Sales_by_Region', count(*) as '# of Dist in state'
from dist, Regions_US
where dist.state=Regions_US.State
group by Region
ORDER BY AVG(sales) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s not ignoring your `ORDER BY` because `FORMAT()` converts the numbers into strings. So what you are seeing is the `ORDER BY` based on string format.

So what you should do is order based on the non-formatted value. I would suggest doing this:

```
select Region, AVG(sales) as 'Average_Sales_by_Region_NUMERICAL', CONCAT('$', FORMAT(Average_Sales_by_Region_NUMERICAL, 0)) as 'Average_Sales_by_Region', count(*) as '# of Dist in state'
from dist, Regions_US
where dist.state=Regions_US.State
group by Region
ORDER BY Average_Sales_by_Region_NUMERICAL DESC;
```

That should work. And won’t result in `AVG(sales)` being run twice.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   select Region,CONCAT('$', FORMAT(AVG(sales), 0)) as 'Average_Sales_by_Region',count(*) as '# of Dist in state'
   from dist, Regions_US
   where dist.state=Regions_US.State
   group by Region
   ORDER BY FORMAT(AVG(sales),0) DESC;
```