# How can I use DISTINCT in MySQL query without it displaying that field in output?

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL query:

```
select Region,
CONCAT('$', FORMAT(AVG(sales), 0)) as 'Average_Sales_by_Region', 
count(*) as '# of Dist in state'
from dist, Regions_US
where dist.state=Regions_US.State
group by Region ORDER BY AVG(sales) DESC;
```

Here is the output from the above MySQL query:

```
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Region             | Average_Sales_by_Region       | # of Dist in state      |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Alaska-Hawaii      | $8,150                        |                       4 |
| Mountain           | $20,216                       |                      74 |
| West North Central | $18,268                       |                      40 |
| South Atlantic     | $16,225                       |                     178 |
| East South Central | $14,967                       |                      30 |
| West South Central | $13,704                       |                     125 |
| East North Central | $12,668                       |                      79 |
| New England        | $11,916                       |                      32 |
| Pacific            | $11,553                       |                     120 |
| Middle Atlantic    | $10,292                       |                     131 |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

There is a field called company_name and I want to do a DISTINCT on it:

```
select DISTINCT company_name,
Region,CONCAT('$', FORMAT(AVG(sales), 0)) as 'Average_Sales_by_Region', 
count(*) as '# of Dist in state'
from dist, Regions_US
where dist.state=Regions_US.State
group by Region ORDER BY AVG(sales) DESC;
```

I want to it to be DISTINCT on the field name of 'company_name', but I don't want the company_name field to be displayed in the output. Is there a way to do a DISTINCT company_name without it being displayed? What is the syntax for it and where would it go on the above MySQL query? Or is there another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: distinct apply all the fields, not company_name only!

Comment: Are you sure about that? Can you provide a source that explains that? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/distinct.php

Comment: Thanks! So is there another method in MySQL to use if you want to have the distinct be specific to one field only? Would doing a sub-query be the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Add it to the `GROUP BY` clause and remove it from the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
  Region,
  CONCAT('$', FORMAT(avgSales, 0)) as 'Average_Sales_by_Region', 
  TheCount as '# of Dist in state'
FROM
(
   SELECT 
     Region, 
     AVG(Sales) avgSales, 
     COUNT(*) theCount
   from dist, Regions_US
   where dist.state=Regions_US.State
   group by Region,company_name
) AS sub       
ORDER BY avgSales DESC;
```

---

**Update:** If you want to select the `sales` as well as the `AVG(sales)` in the same `SELECT` clause, you can't do this and you shouldn't. MySQL allows you to do so, but you will get an arbitrary value for `sales` for each group of `Region, company_name`.

This is called *the single value rule* when using a `GROUP BY` and it is standard to follow this. This means, every column in the `SELECT` clause, must be in either an a `GROUP BY` or an aggregate functions. You can't select a row that is not in a `GROUP BY` nor in an aggregate function. In your case you already select the `sales` with an aggregate function `AVG`, why you want to select `sales` also in the same query?

**However**, If you want to do this anyway, you can do this:

```
SELECT
  Region,
  CONCAT('$', FORMAT(avgSales, 0)) as 'Average_Sales_by_Region', 
  TheCount as '# of Dist in state',
  (SELECT sales
   FROM dist d2
   WHERE d2.Region       = d1.Region
     AND d2.company_name = d1.company_name) AS Sales
FROM
(
   SELECT 
     Region, 
     AVG(Sales) avgSales, 
     COUNT(*) theCount
   from dist
   INNER JOIN Regions_US ON dist.state = Regions_US.State
   group by Region,company_name
) AS sub       
ORDER BY avgSales DESC;
```

Assuming that `Region, company_name` are coming form the `dist` table.

**Note that:** I used `INNER JOIN` instead of the implicit join syntax in your query, they are the same.

But I am not sure for the consistent of the `sales` values for each group of `Region, Company_name`.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Can you explain how 'AVG(Sales) avgSales,' works?

Comment: @Edward `avgSales` is an alias, `AVG(Sales) AS avgSales` but the `AS` keyword is optional so it is the same as `AVG(Sales) avgSales`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error message which doesn't make sense to me:
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'sales' in 'field list'. sales is in the dist table.

Comment: @Edward Add it to the inner select so that you can select it in the outer query.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with complex MySQL queries to know how to adapt this. Would you be so kind as to provide the entire query? Thanks!

Comment: @Edward OK, but how do you want to select both `sales` and `AVG(Sales)` in the same query? Every value that in the select clause must appear in either in the group by clause or in an aggregate function. Can you please show me some sample data with the desired output? it will be very helpful.

Comment: I added sample data from the first example of the MySQL query. That output looks fine, but I know the table has duplicated rows which is why I wanted to do a DISTINCT on the company_name. Thanks!

Comment: The reason there is "...select the sales with an aggregate function AVG, why you want to select sales..." in the same query is because that was the answer to my other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586912/why-is-mysql-with-format-ignoring-order/14587086#14587086

Comment: Yes, I did. MySQL is complaining about d2. I'm trying to figure it out. Thanks again for your help!